# Sitefinity 4 - Requiring Login

Tags: sitefinity-4

I'm extremely new to Sitefinity and I'm wanting to create a section of my website that will require a user to login for them to view it. I would like to be able to create a widget and drag it onto the page template I'm using for this section and have it check for a specific role.

Is there anything that already exists that I could use? Or do I need to build something from scratch? If I need to build one from scratch, could someone point me in the right direction?

I'm using a fresh installation of Sitefinity 4.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Small world! :)

For others looking for an answer, please reference [this forum thread](http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/forums/sitefinity-4-x/developing-with-sitefinity/requiring-login.aspx#1954764) regarding the issue.

Comment: You're finding me everywhere :)